# Запуск старой игры на макос с wine(Lego Racer 1)?

Tags: macos, wine

Разработчики вайна утверждают ,что можно можно.Я поставил вайн:`brew install wine`

Перенес папку с Lego Racer'ом на мак и выполнил:

```
wine LEGORacers.exe
```

Получаю черный экран.Жду некоторое время ничего нету ,
жму command+option+esc.Вернулся к привычному экрану:

Логи в iterm2:

```
0009:err:quartz:GetClassMediaFile Media class not found
0009:fixme:quartz:Parser_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:quartz:VideoRendererInner_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:quartz:VideoRendererInner_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:strmbase:TransformFilterImpl_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:err:msvideo:ICLocate Required media codec 'vidc IV50' not found!
0009:fixme:quartz:DSoundRender_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:strmbase:MemInputPin_NotifyAllocator Read only flag not handled yet!
[1]    708 terminated  wine LEGORacers.exe
wineserver crashed, please enable coredumps (ulimit -c unlimited) and restart.
```

Что не так?

**P.S** прошу не бросать язвительные шутки.(и не голосовать против :))

#### Update

Собственно проблемой я вижу то ,что не полетит ли мой мак если я сделаю :

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

(так советует wine)
Особенно с учетом ,что :

```
➜  ~ ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
-u: processes                       5625
-n: file descriptors                256
```

Comment: _не полетит ли мой мак если я сделаю_  делайте, не полетит.

Comment: Извиняюсь если вопрос немного "не по теме" или просто глупый.И еще, я так понимаю я даю возможность записовать "coredumps" я не думаю ,что они чем-то полезны.Как мне их потом удалять(я не хочу загромождть мак).Отключить их записи я так понимаю вот так:`ulimit -c 0` да?

Comment: Да, так выключите дамп.

Comment: Спасибо @0xdb я так понял ,что если я выключу дамп то он будет удален... или нет?(просто имеется опыт с тормозном маком из-за загроможденности)

Comment: _если я выключу дамп то он будет удален_ - нет, он не будет больше создаватъся, уже созданый удалите ручками.

Comment: А где он будет (чтобы его удалить ручками)?Вот в чем вопрос!

Comment: В текущей папке посмотрите, он будет как-то так называтся - core*

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь :) !Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Попробовал:фиг на выходе.Опять черный экран.